# PayPal and Sandbox payment credentials : sandbox and production fields

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

im very new with this API. I want to generate a PayPal PAY button. I've created a SANDBOX Paypal as a vendor and as a buyer. Two accounts.

I don't know how to get 'sandbox' and 'production' fields.

I haven't created an APP, all the time ask me to confirm and email which I've confirmed 10 times.

```
         paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
        client: {
            sandbox:    'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AULfweezb3a.97AL03QEPQS.cIvX',
            production: 'QGWT5LPKXCYKNMEW'
        },

        // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
        commit: true,
```

...

i dont know how to get sandbox and production fields, inside 'client' object.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create email confirmed and verified sandbox account, please refer the below steps:

```
1. Login to http://developer.paypal.com/ with your LIVE PayPal account
2. Click Dashboard
3. Click sandbox accounts
4. Click Create account button on the top right corner
5. Create a business account for seller and a personal account for buyer
6. Please add bank account and credit card and also populate some amount to your account
7. The email address need not be an real one.
```

Please refer the below link for your reference for creating sandbox:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Refer the following links for PayPal Express checkout client side integrations, where you can find steps to get the client id details:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client